# How to put utf8 characters in alias?

Tags: joomla-3.x, url, sef

I am trying to set Chinese URLs for my Joomla site. However, I can't just put Chinese characters in the "alias"; I've also tried putting in url-encoded utf8 characters like `%E7%9A%84`, but it will be converted to something like `e7-9a-84`. So does Joomla 3.8.1 officially support utf8 characters in URL? Or do I have to find some extension(I have heard "sh404SEF" is good but it is not free and most of its functions are not very useful for me)?

Comment: You cannot set the translated URL to the by setting alias from the Joomla, to do it you can either edit menu item path value to the desired one using DB query or simply by changing the parameter to the table #__menu, this is the only way I could achieve it if someone has a better way please add.

Comment: You may award your answer the green tick, so that it is deemed "resolved" and stops getting bumped.

Answer (score 0):

Today after I upgraded to 3.8.2 I find out the Unicode Alias setting in "global configuration-seo setting" is actually working now. There is no more problem filling in unicode in alias.

Comment: it actually was working since 3.0 and may be even 2.5